# How to use python selenium to search homeaway.com and using the calendar dropdown field?

Tags: python, date, selenium, calendar

I'd like to use python selenium to search at https://www.homeaway.com/

The following works:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.homeaway.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='searchKeywords']").send_keys("Philadelphia, PA, USA")
```

But I'm running into an issue using the the calendar dropdown date picker, as it's not taking any of the values.

I've tried the following

Attempt 1 to enter a date into the start and end date field:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='stab-searchbox-start-date']").send_keys("02/01/2017")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='stab-searchbox-end-date']").send_keys("03/01/2017")
```

Note: It looks like homeaway website is completely ignoring the above commands unless you mannually click on the website with your mouse and then use the above selenium commands. In other words, the above commands are not working without a manual mouse click on the website first.

Attempt 2 to enter a date into the start and end date field:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='2017-02-01_2017-02']").click()
```

Attempt 3 to enter a date into the start and end date field

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('#stab-searchbox-start-date')[0].value = '02/01/2017'")
driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('#stab-searchbox-end-date')[0].value = '03/01/2017'")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg searchbox-submit js-searchSubmit']").click()
```

Note: this looks like it works, but the dates are actually not registered when you click on search despite the dates being entered into the star and end date text boxes. It seems that homeaway will only register the dates if you use the calendar dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can not send_keys in these types when input text is not supported.

try this code, it will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url='http://www.homeaway.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("search-location").send_keys("Philadelphia, PA, USA")

driver.find_element_by_id('search-checkin').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]//*[text()="30"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_id('search-checkout').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]//*[text()="31"]').click()
```